# Add custom font in HTML page

Tags: html, css, font-face

I want to add a custom font to my html email template. i uploaded the font on the server and everything...but i think i made a mistake somewhere. below is the code.

```
<tr>
<td align="center" mc:edit="title1">
<style type="text/css">

@font-face {  
    src: url('http://www.screenmedia.mk/EmailMarketing/00PEDANTIX.TTF');
    src: url('http://www.screenmedia.mk/EmailMarketing/00PEDANTIXBOLD.TTF');
}

h6 { 
    font-family: 00PEDANTIX;

}
</style>

<h6 class="h6 t bold" style="font-family: 00PEDANTIX; src: url('http://www.screenmedia.mk/EmailMarketing/00PEDANTIX.TTF'); font-weight: 700;color: #fff;font-size: 20px;line-height: 15px;margin: 0 0 8px !important; p   adding-left: 80px;"><singleline label="title1">SILVER</singleline></h6>
```

-->

```
</td>
</tr>
```

EDITED:

```
<tr>
<td align="center" mc:edit="title1">
<style type="text/css">

@font-face {
font-family: 00PEDANTIX;
src: url('http://www.screenmedia.mk/EmailMarketing/00PEDANTIX.TTF');
}
@font-face {
font-family: 00PEDANTIXBOLD;
src: url('http://www.screenmedia.mk/EmailMarketing/00PEDANTIXBOLD.TTF');
font-weight: bold;
}

h6 {

font-family: 00PEDANTIX;
}

</style>

<h6 class="h6 t bold" style="font-family: 00PEDANTIX; font-weight: 700;color: #fff;font-size: 20px;line-height: 15px;margin: 0 0 8px !important; padding-left: 80px;"><singleline label="title1">SILVER</singleline></h6>
<table width="60" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;"><tbody>
<tr>

</tr></tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Also, you only need to define the source once, and it needs to be in @font-face.  You can remove the src: from your inline style.

Comment: Beware...custom fonts is not supported in all mail clients - https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3897/using-web-fonts-in-email

Comment: @Luis P.A. thnx for the tip Luis

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the font family in the @font-face rule. Also you can only define one weight per @font-face

```
@font-face {
font-family: 00PEDANTIX;
src: url('http://www.screenmedia.mk/EmailMarketing/00PEDANTIX.TTF');
}
@font-face {
font-family: 00PEDANTIXBOLD;
src: url('http://www.screenmedia.mk/EmailMarketing/00PEDANTIXBOLD.TTF');
font-weight: bold;
}
```

Edit: Didn't read that it was for an email template.  You can't load custom fonts in email, yet. If you need to use that font, The only way you could do this is through images.

Comment: ah ok. btw why it still doesent work when i open it in browser ? like a normal html file. i edited my question and i have the code which is below "EDITED" section, and it still doesent work :/

Comment: Huh for some reason it doesn't want to load from the domain you are using. I tried downloading the font and linking it, and it worked fine.  Is it your domain?  If so make sure you have .ttf defined in your web.config

Comment: yah it works now. the font loads even from the server now. the problem was that we had to put quotes in font-family: '00PEDANTIXBOLD'; and not : font-family: 00PEDANTIXBOLD; but maybe they'll not appear in emails?! thnx a lot guys!

Comment: Yeah, that might be because the font name begins with numbers. No, unfortunately it is still unlikely that they will appear in emails.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the browser takes a while or doesn't supports the web fonts.

Try http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator to generate the font face code and it will work with most of the browsers.

They will generate different versions (OTF, TTF etc) of fonts for webkit, mobile, IE and mozilla.

... and its FREE!!!

Answer (score 0):

Some versions of any browsers not support ttf fonts. You can consult if your browser is compatible in this site [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fontface)